# Similarity/approximate queries in Solr

Tags: solr, full-text-search

What is the simplest way to query Solr for the documents that contain text similiar to a (longish) passage. This is similar to what ElasticSearch `match` queries do or what probabilistic search engines like Indri do by default. This is something between an `and` and an `or` query. None of the terms is required, but you get documents that contain many of the terms. You can also just pass a passage of raw text to the engine and it returns documents with high term overlap with the passage without having to try to parse or tokenize the text in the client. The best I option can see in the Solr query reference is to tokenize the query text myself and then insert an OR between each pair of terms and return the top N results. Is there more concise way of doing it with Solr?

Comment: see https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThisHandler and http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/MoreLikeThis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer above is correct. You can choose to find documents similar to another document in the index, similar to a given external URL or similar to some given text. You can choose what field(s) to target and various other parameters. Here's the official Solr Reference Guide documentation page for MLT: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/MoreLikeThis